# Two canvas' layered on top of each other in a div container?

Tags: css, html

I been trying to get two canvas' to lay on top of each other whilst inside another div but they won't do it. They end up under each other.

The way i have set it up is like this:

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.canvas{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
```

With this for output:

```
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="layer1" class="canvas" style="z-index:1;"></canvas>
  <canvas id="layer2" class="canvas" style="z-index:2;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Any idea how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parent container need to have `position: relative` set

Change your CSS accordingly:

```
.container{
   width:100%;
   height:300px;
   margin:0 auto;
   position: relative; /* add */
}
.canvas{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute; /* change */
   left: 0; 
   top: 0;
}
```

Then change the class of the canvas containers to `class="canvas"`  OR change the CSS to just `canvas` without the dot OR if you prefer change the CSS class to `.c`

Comment: It seems you were first to answer so i'll give you the tick :) Thanks for the help it works now!

Comment: Can't seem to tick for another 4 minutes yet.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I think your classes are labeled as `c` instead of `canvas`.

Second, relative needs to be changed to absolute (on your canvas) so they can float above each other.

```
.canvas{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `position: relative` of your canvases to `absolute`

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative; /* this to make the canvases children of the div.container */
}

.canvas{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute; /* this to position them */
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
```